# Look steam inventory by trade offer link in node js

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api

I want to check steam inventory using trade offer link

I know about method with parse from url like `steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/…`

But it have limit: 3 tries for hour.
I know smth about method with trade offer link.
I need to check about 100-200 inventories for hour and I know trade offer link each steam user witch needed to check.

How to do this in Node?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.